# Middle height dot like `\vdots`

Tags: symbols

I am trying to make actually a "`\vdot`" instead of `\vdots`. What I am trying to achieve is something like that

[image]

I tried `\vdot`(within `$$`) in the sence of `\cdots` and `\cdot` but it's not recognised as a command. Is there a way to print this dot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this: `$(6\cdot 5 \cdot 3)$`? It works for me.

```
$(6\cdot 5 \cdot 3)$
```

[image]

Comment: What an &%*0t(I am reffering to me)... Sure it does! You are absolutely right!It is working! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Thanos. OK I'm sure that you could be find the solution by yourself after some tests... We're still celebrating last night.. lol

Comment: Yeah you are right; on both I guess :P